# Bhishma ekadashi festival

Tags: festivals, bhishma

Generally Bhishma Ekadasi is celebrated on Magha Suddha Ekadasi. It is learnt that Bhishma died on Ashtami. Why the festival is being celebrated on Ekadasi?

Comment: "It is learnt that Bhishma died on Ashtami" can you please add a valid source for this?